# Understanding Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract and other core Zend classes

Tags: zend-framework, abstract-class, subclass, overriding

I am digging deep into the Zend framework and at this point I am a little confused. I am particularly checking out the Zend_Controller_Action (*_Action), Zend_Controller_Request_HTTP(*_HTTP) and Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract (*_Abstract).

The *_Abstract class as it's name suggests is an abstract class hence cannot be instantiated and mostly provides method stubs along with a few final implementations. The actual implementation is in *_HTTP and *_Simple classes that subclass *_Abstract. Fair enough.

Now I am looking at the *_Action class, right here: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.0/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Action.html

Taking a look at $_request variable, it states that it is an instance of type *_Abstract. At this point, I am confused since I do not know why it should be of type *_Abstract and not *_Http since one cannot technically have an instance of an abstract class.

So my question:

1. Why is an instance of an abstract class being declared here.

Moving on, I want to override the $_request classes's getParams() method since this is how our application retrieves all parameters and I would like to apply some common sanitization and blacklisting rules to all of our input right here.

Unfortunately, when in my BaseController (the Main Controller that is subclassed by all other controllers) I declare something to the effect of :

```
$_request = new RequestClass(); //RequestClass subclasses Zend_Controller_Request_Http and overrides getParams()
```

my application does not launch itself the way it ought (I get a blank screen).

For those more curious, RequestClass() getParams() does nothing fancy but:

```
getParams()
{
  $params = parent::getParams();
  //sanitization rules over $params;
  return $params;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type hint of `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` effectively means the request must be an instance of a class that extends `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`.

Unless you're delibrately not using ZF's routing, you'll probably be better off doing your sanitation of parameters through the routes. Otherwise, if you're getting a blank screen, that means `display_errors` is turned off and the PHP error or exception is being logged instead. Check your web server error log to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: can you please elaborate on sanitizing through ZF's routing ?

Comment: You can specify in your routes that parameters should match a particular set or values, or a particular regular expression pattern. Example here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard.variable-requirements (ZF1)

Comment: thanks Tim, the example you linked me to seems to be for URL parameters only, I could not quite find how to use ZF routing for setting variable requirements for POST parameters. Particularly I am simply trying to block Javascript (<script> tags) in our app

Comment: Avoiding XSS is something you should do at the view level - `$this->escape($something)` - not at the request parameter level.

Comment: Yes, but that is escaping data in my output, this is more of a security precaution from an input point of view